# In Android SQLite, working directly with Cursor is more memory efficient than creating Model Objects?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-sqlite, android-cursor, android-memory

In most of the **Android** sample codes, populating a **ListView** from **SQLite** database is done in two ways,

1. **Prefetch data to List -** Execute query, create Model objects for each row then add it to a **List** and **close** the **Cursor**, then populate **ListView** with **List**.
2. **Without List and Model objects -** Execute query and populate **ListView** by following the **Cursor** using **moveToFirst**, **moveToLast**, **move**, as required.

Now I want to know, which of the above method is more memory efficient, in **Android** ?

Comment: 1 million * 5KB is **5 GB**, right???

Comment: It is not exact count. But wanted to know, if it is that much big size ? any way I will update the question, to make it 500MB.

Comment: Now much better and acceptable... :)

Comment: Ok, but I want know the best practice, to handle the case.

Comment: Please test all possibilities now you have the chance. Report here.

Comment: Updated to make it more acceptable. Now dealing with 50MB only. I think, 100 thousand records is not big, if a number of related tables involved.

Comment: Consider **indexing** the fields involved in the **WHERE clauses** and also the **JOIN constaints**. I had an average performance boost of about 350x (yes, threee hundred and fifty times faster than without indexing)

Comment: It is ok to add indexing to optimize SQLite querying. But what about handling the query result and the options in question ? Is the first or second one you prefer in that case ? As far I know, the third one is not required, Googling about Cursor made me to think so, about third option.

Comment: @MohammedMT I think you should ask to DBAs here: http://www.dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: @userX:Actually it is to know which one is more memory efficient in case of Android. May be will need to change the title so.

Comment: @MohammedMT ok...got it...and now title is good.

Comment: Thnx for comments :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Cursor` approach is more memory efficient:

Suppose you have 1000 entries in your database and you have a ListView which can show 10 entries at the same time. If you create a list at first, you'll have to create 1000 model objects (each of which in turn consists of several objects depending on the number of columns of your table) and the listview creates additional 10 views (actually some more, depending on the layout of the list) for displaying the 10 items. Now when the user scrolls the list, in your Adapter you end up copying data from your model objects to the list item views currently in view.

On the other hand, if you use a `CursorAdapter`, whenever you have to fill a list item with data, you are provided with the Cursor holding exactly the data for that row and you can simply pick the data of the columns you actually need to be displayed in the list item. No need for creating the 1000 model objects.

From a code readability perspective, a model approach would be better because working with Cursors is quite low level, you'll need to know the names of the columns in the database and so on.

Comment: Have any References to learn how Android manages Cursor internally ?

Comment: I don't have a specific one at hand right now. I know that SQLiteCursor inherits from `AbstractWindowedCursor`, meaning it keeps a number of rows around the current position in memory. To learn all about the internals you can look at the Android source code which is (most of the time) quite easy to read and has very good comments.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `Service` or at least `Thread/Async` so your UI thread will **not** be blocked. `Service` is better because people can go to other apps while downloading. You can use `BroadcastReceiver` to communicate with your running `Service`.

Comment: It is about the UI performance. I need to know how to manage the query result also, and the question is more related to that area.

Comment: you do not answer the question ;)

Comment: @mithrop: what answer ? and who ? :)

Comment: @Mohammed : Blaze do not answer the question and discuss another point : using Service to make SQLite request. It's not your question ;)

Comment: @mithrop:Okey...Actually I am a beginner to Android. I saw many examples using Model Object. So I had this doubt in my mind. So I posted it here. Anyway I almost got the answer.I think Ridcully is right.

Comment: Your question is perfectly OK. It's a good point and I am interested by the answer ;) Accept the Ridcully answer if it's ok ;)